# Chrome memory leak using Selenium and Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium in Python to perform some web scraping in Chrome. The scraper loads a page, types a search in a searchbox, solves a basic captcha, scrapes the data, and repeats.

### Problem

The `chrome.exe` process memory usage climbs continually, while the Python and `chromedriver.exe` processes have stable memory usage.

The memory leaked by Chrome is proportional to the number of pages loaded, so after around 600 pages scraped my Chrome window will run out of memory. "Google Chrome ran out of memory while trying to display this webpage."

[image: Performance Monitor tracking process memory usage over a 10-minute period]

### My workaround

Workaround 1: Set a counter to load N pages before running `driver.quit()`, followed by `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` to relaunch the browser. But the memory quickly fills up again.

Workaround 2: Use Firefox with gecko webdriver instead. This has constant memory usage without a memory leak.

### Version Details

OS: Windows 10 Education 1909 18363.836

Python Version: 3.8.3

Selenium Version: 3.141.0

Chrome Version: 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

ChromeDriver: 83.0.4103.39

Comment: @OscarVanL Did you post in Selenium Github issues?